# Floating point operations in GCC

Tags: gcc, linker, floating-point, sh

Anyone knows where can I find the floating functions for non FPU processor (SH-3) called __mulsf3, __divsf3, __addsf3, __subsf3, __ltsf2 and __floatsisf. I read that those functions are in libgcc but linking against libgcc does not work. Also I read that SH3 devs moved those functions to another lib (maybe libfloat or libgcc_os).

Anyone has a clue? I would prefer to have a look at the source.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, many of these are generated during GCC's build process and they are highly dependent on system and architecture.

What I do know for sure it that LLVM's `compiler-rt` strives to provide an alternative. The sources are located here:

http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/compiler-rt/trunk/lib/

Answer (score 0):

The implementation details have changed over time, but they're supposed to be in libgcc. However, SH being a multilib system, maybe you're trying to link to the wrong libgcc?